# Recursive categories fetch and view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have categories and subcategories in my view. The code looks like this

```
<ul>
  <% Category.roots.each do |category| %>
  <li class="col-md-2">
    <a href="#"><%= category.name %></a>
    <% if !category.children.empty? %>
    <ul>
      <%= category.decorate.draw_tree %>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I'm basically using a `decorator` to make it recursive

```
class CategoryDecorator < Draper::Decorator

  delegate_all
  decorates :category

  def draw_tree

    children.inject("") do |memo, child|

      memo << "<li class=\"dir\"><a href=\"#\">#{child.name}</a>"
      memo << "<ul>#{child.decorate.draw_tree}</ul>" if not child.children.empty?
      memo << "</li>"

    end.html_safe

  end


end
```

It works fine. But I'm writing HTML inside a Ruby class and I don't like the idea, I'de like to keep it in the view. I tried to play with `&block` to turn it like following

```
<ul>
  <% Category.roots.each do |category| %>
  <li class="col-md-2">
    <a href="#"><%= category.name %></a>
    <% if !category.children.empty? %>
    <ul>
      <% category.decorate.draw_tree do |child| %>

      <li class="dir"><a href="#"><%= child.name %></a>
      <% if child.children.any %>
        <ul><%= child.decorate.draw_tree %></ul>"
      <% end %>
      </li>"

      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Sadly, I couldn't make it work so far. I think I lack methodology here. How can I rewrite this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working solution**

The correct answer to my own question was the method `content = capture { yield }` which allows you to get the whole block content, so you can manipulate it entirely somewhere else and use recursivity.

I saw the answer in some random code after giving up to organize my code this way, a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it:

In your view, simply call a recursive method on each category:

```
<ul>
  <% Category.roots.map do |category| %>
     <%= draw_tree(category) %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And now in a helper file (`app/helpers/category_helper.rb`?), this is the "right" place to put HTML helpers. First, in pseudo-code:

```
def draw_tree(category)
  <li class="col-md-2">
    <a href="#"><%= category.name %></a>
    <% category.children.each do |child| %>
    <ul>
      <%= draw_tree(child) %>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
  </li>
end
```

Now, to actually make this work, rather than writing a string and calling `#html_safe`, a much cleaner (and generally safer) approach is to use [`content_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag). The end result is:

```
def draw_tree(category)
  content_tag(:li, class: "col-md-2") do
    link_to('#', category.name)
    category.children.map do |child|
      content_tag(:ul, draw_tree(child))
    end
  end
end
```

I haven't actually run the above code, so apologies if there's some small mistake. But hopefully you get the idea :)